# Why isn't SUBSTR stopping at the end index using instr?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a string value I'd like to make more presentable:

```
'Course grade for <font color="#FF0000">Student Name</font>'
```

but my query to extract the Student Name:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, instr(col, '>',1,1)+1, instr(col, '<',1,2)) FROM my_table where course_id=1
```

returns `Student Name</font>` despite `instr('<',1,2)` returning the correct index.

I'm not sure why it doesn't stop on that index and returns the rest of the string. Ideally I'd like it to return **Student Name**

Many thanks!

Comment: SUBSTR(char, position [, **substring_length** ]) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subtract the start of the string, as the second paramter is length and `INSTR` counts from the start

> ```
> CREATE TABLE my_table (course_id int,col varchar2(200))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,'Course grade for <font color="#FF0000">Student Name</font>')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,'Course grade for <font color="#FF0000">abel </font>')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTR(col, instr(col, '>',1,1)+1, instr(col, '</',1,1) -  instr(col, '>',1,1) - 1) FROM my_table where course_id=1
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTR(COL,INSTR(COL,'>',1,1)+1,INSTR(COL,'</',1,1)-INSTR(COL,'>',1,1)-1) |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Student Name                                                              |
> | abel                                                                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9f18545a26893327007d7ae187b20a1)*